# JSF PrimeFaces - Button Height doesn't change

Tags: css, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I am dealing with primeface framework **sentinel theme** in a JSF page. I understand most of the issue, but I lock in changing button height.

I have tried giving 
`style="height:100px"` or `style="line-height:100px"` or `styleClass="Fs25"` to `<p:button />` but button's colored area never changes.

I look default login.xhtml of sentinel theme and I see the button and copy the code, result is the same in my page again.

What is my problem guys. What is the point I miss over and over?

[image: small][image]

Here is live preview [Login Page](http://www.primefaces.org/sentinel/login.xhtml)

Comment: Did inspect the element (e.g. with Chrome)? Maybe another style class overrides your settings. You can try `height:100px !important`, although it is not best practice.

Comment: I didn't try in chrome but the situation, I opened login.xhtml with mozilla also @simdevmon

Comment: Here is live preview http://www.primefaces.org/sentinel/login.xhtml @simdevmon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after I inspect the css I have found

```
.ui-button .ui-button-text {
    display: block;
    line-height: normal;
}
```

This is how I solved the issue

inside `head` tags

```
<style>
#bigbtn .ui-button-text{
    line-height: 60px; <!-- Height of Button -->
    font-size: 20px;   <!-- Size of Button Text --> 
}
</style>
```

In `body`

```
<div id="bigbtn">
   <p:button value="Big Button" />
</div>
```

There could be better answer. I also want to hear them.
Thank you.